# post_mime_types Filter not Working in List Mode

Tags: filters, wp-admin

I'm using the following code to add new sorting options to my Media Library:

```
function modify_post_mime_types( $post_mime_types ) {

    $post_mime_types['application/pdf'] = array( __( 'PDFs' ), __( 'Manage PDFs' ), _n_noop( 'PDF <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'PDFs <span class="count">(%s)</span>' ) );
    $post_mime_types['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation'] = array( __( 'Powerpoints' ), __( 'Manage Powerpoints' ), _n_noop( 'Powerpoints <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Powerpoints <span class="count">(%s)</span>' ) );
    $post_mime_types['application/msword, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'] = array( __( 'Documents' ), __( 'Manage Documents' ), _n_noop( 'Documents <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Documents <span class="count">(%s)</span>' ) );

    return $post_mime_types;

}

add_filter( 'post_mime_types', 'modify_post_mime_types' );
```

---

Which appears to be working great for the JavaScript-enabled "Grid" mode:

### [image: PDFs Grid]

However, in the "List" mode, clicking on the entries shows all the extensions/files (even though it is counting them properly) as shown:

### [image: PDFs List]

Here's the URL it is redirecting to for the PDFs:

wp-admin/upload.php?mode=list&attachment-filter=post_mime_type%3Aapplication%252Fpdf&m=0&filter_action=Filter&s&action=-1&paged=1&action2=-1&affected&_ajax_nonce=093720f202&ps

If I try with the standard Wordpress "Images" filter, it indeed works. Here's the URL it gives for that:

wp-admin/upload.php?mode=list&attachment-filter=post_mime_type%3Aimage&m=0&filter_action=Filter&s&action=-1&paged=1&action2=-1&affected&_ajax_nonce=093720f202&ps

I'm thinking this is perhaps a Wordpress bug, but just making sure if anybody knows anything here.

Comment: I have a decent workaround here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/170471/34438

Comment: @kitchin Sorry, I can't comment on that yet, so hopefully you get this. For some reason it doesn't look like it is getting all the files. Just as an example, it says PDFs (10), but when I filter, it's only returning the same 4 files. The "Grid" mode returns the proper amount. It doesn't seem to be a file naming issue or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the `attachment-filter=` URL parameter. The slash between `application/pdf` (or else) is being escaped twice. When you replace the `%252F` with a slash or `%2F` the filter will work.

The first escaping (`/` becomes `%2F`) happens when WP is building the selectbox containing the mime types. The second one (`%2F` becomes `%252F`) is performed by the browser.

The easiest Solution would be to manually urldecode the URL param somewhere in PHP:

```
if ( isset( $_GET['attachment-filter'] ) )
    $_GET['attachment-filter'] = urldecode($_GET['attachment-filter']);
```

**Update:** There is a WP core ticket on that issue: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/30123

Once this gets fixed, the answer above will be obsolete.

Comment: Do you know where this code could be implemented? Just as a quick hack I added it to functions.php and wp-admin/index.php with no success.

Comment: The code needs to be executed in the backend. Neither of `wp-admin/index.php` and `functions.php` is. It chould live either in a plugin or in a mu-plugin. Inside the `modify_post_mime_types` function above might also be a good place.